# i want after editing of tableview cell textfield ,when i type i want auto suggestion of word

Tags: javafx-8

this code contain basically how to edit the textfield of tableview column ,like tableview column is in textfield format and i need to edit it and when i will type i need auto suggestion but my auto suggestion code is not working ,so can anyone suggest me or help to overcome my auto suggestion of word problem with the same procedure ,in createfield after commitedit i called learnword function as well but that is not happening.

```
class EditingCell extends TableCell<File, String> {
         Set<String> possibleWordSet= new HashSet<>();
        private AutoCompletionBinding<String> autoCompletionBinding;


        public TextField textField;
        //private Object possibleWordSet;

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {

            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
                System.out.println(textField.getCaretPosition() + "caret position");

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            setText(getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                System.out.println("I am in update function");
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(item);
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        // Instantiates the text field.
        public void createTextField() {

            textField = new TextField(getItem());
            System.out.println("hello i am inside the createtextfield");


            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
                    autoCompletionBinding =  TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, possibleWordSet); /tion/for auto suuges

            textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {

                        commitEdit(textField.getText());//on  enter event editing of textfield
                         learnword(textField.getText());//for auto suggestion call learnword method.

                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });


            textField.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    int caretPosition = textField.getCaretPosition();
                    GUIFXMLDocumentController fx = new GUIFXMLDocumentController();
                    fx.setCaretPos(caretPosition);
                    System.out.println(caretPosition + "caretPosition");
                    fx.setTextField(textField);
                }
            });
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                    if (!arg2) {
                        System.out.println(textField.getText() + "Inside changeListener------------------");
                        GUIFXMLDocumentController.tv_new.getFocusModel().focusNext();
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                         learnword(textField.getText());

                    }

                }
            });


        }
                 public void learnword(String text) {
            possibleWordSet.add(text);
            if(autoCompletionBinding!=null){
                autoCompletionBinding.dispose();
            }
            autoCompletionBinding =  TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, possibleWordSet);




    }
    }

    enter code here
```